# Creating a notepad file and then open it error in C#

Tags: c#, notepad

I am trying to do a simple exercise.
My aim is to create a notepad file and then open it.

I have this in the Main:

```
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Files\notepadExercise.txt", "Hello");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Files\notepadExercise.txt");
    }
```

I get the following response:

> The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

I don't understand what I have done wrong, as it looks correct to me.

Does anyone have a tip as to what I should change to make it work?

Comment: a text file is not an executable file. you don't start the .txt file, you start notepad _with_ the .txt-file.

Comment: you *"can't"* execute a .txt file. However, you can execute `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" "C:\Files\notepadExercise.txt"`

Comment: Above comments and answer are both incorrect and usable. The code provided by the question is quite valid. Using Process.Start on any file recognized by the OS must open the associated program. Thus an EXE will be launched and a TXT will be opened by the (factory default) Notepad. Here the problem is elsewhere. Are you on Windows? Maybe your system is corrupted: https://superuser.com/questions/799266/how-to-restore-the-ability-to-modify-the-association-for-the-txt-file-extension | https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

I think `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` would help. You can give it a `ProcessStartInfo` with the `Open` verb and set the `UseShellExecute` property. This is essentially what Windows does when you double-click the file in Windows Explorer.

With the way you're doing it, you need to specify the full-qualified path to `notepad.exe`. You can't assume `C:\Windows` either as the user might've installed Windows elsewhere. You can use environment variables for that, though:

`Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%WINDIR%"), "System32\notepad.exe")`.

Once you have the fully-qualified path for Notepad.exe, you pass the filename you want to open as an argument to notepad. Like writing this in a command prompt:

```
> notepad.exe C:\path\to\my\file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach to open the file.

```cs
void Main()
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\notepadExercise.txt", "Hello");
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\notepadExercise.txt") { UseShellExecute = true });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not able to figure out how to use the notepad.exe. You can use `Process.Start`, calling `notepad.exe` with the file as a parameter.

Try to specify it also like this: a simplest example:

```
        var filePath = @"C:\Files\notepadExercise.txt";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Hello");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"notepad.exe", filePath);
```